# Dividing values by sum of colum

Tags: mysql, sql, select

What the table looks like:

```
name--value1---value2
name1-----1-------4
name2-----2-------6
```

Output should be:

```
name---value1---value2
name1---.333-----.40      
name2---.666-----.60
```

I  am trying:

```
select (value1/sum(value1), (value2/sum(value2)
from table
```

and it outputs the values for name1 only. When I use group by, it shows a value of 1 for all the values.

I am using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
SELECT value1 / t2.sum_v1,
    value2 / t2.sum_v2
FROM tab INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(value1) AS sum_v1,
    SELECT SUM(value2) AS sum_v2
    FROM tab ) t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to compute the sums as a subquery. So in your case for value1, it would be like this:

```
select (value1 / (select sum(value1) from table)) from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sum the columns and then `join` to that aggregate query:

```
SELECT     name, value1 / sum1, value2/ sum2
FROM       my_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(value1) AS sum1, SUM(value2) AS sum 2
            FROM   my_table) t
```

Note that using `cross join` is OK since the inner query is guaranteed to return a single row.